# How to find ownership of a Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

Some time ago, I created a Google Calendar at calendar.google.com using Chrome Browser, and made it public. This was a calendar *in addition* to the default calendar provided with every Google identity - let's call it calendarX. I then sync'd calendarX with my Thunderbird (Lightning) client, and am still using it today with Thunderbird, to create & view events.

I now need to know the address of calendarX, so that I can share the link with others. So I logged into calendar.google.com with (what I thought were) the credentials of the calendar owner - but calendarX is missing, no reference to it at all.

So maybe I used some other Google identity to create the calendar?

The only clue I have is the calendar properties in Thunderbird (Lightning). It shows:

```
googleapi://MYEMAIL@MYDOMAIN/?calendar=MYDOMAIN_dq0l2urbXXXXlj9gcn5o2en1bc%40group.calendar.google.com
```

Doesn't MYEMAIL@MYDOMAIN imply the ownership of calendarX? That's the Google identity I have checked, and calendarX does NOT appear when I log into calendar.google.com with that identity. The default calendar is there, but not calendarX.

So maybe it's owned by some other identity? How can I find out?

Or how can I find the address of calendarX?

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendars can be found by simply [logging in your CORRECT email address](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2465776?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) which was used to create it. There's no tricky process in that. Just make sure it's your email address and not a service account that was used.

Comment: I thought the correct email address was the one presented above as MYEMAIL@MYDOMAIN. But, since the calendar is not there when I login with that address, I must have used some other address. But I don't know what.  And that's the reason for the question. How to find ownership when the creating email address has been forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

As an Admin of the GSuite system, you can add any calendar to your own account.  If you can find the calendar ID from a user who has access to the calendar by going into the calendar settings is the way I did it, you can just add the calendar to your account using the calendar ID URL, once it is in your account as a super admin you can see who created the calendar and you can change who has access and the rights.  Very simple but not documented anywhere I could find.